# Type 'InitiallyImmediateDeferrableStatic' is not assignable to type 'Deferrable'

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying out sequelize for a personal project and following the v6 documentation.

When setting column options I tried to set the deferrable property to Deferrable.INITIALLY_IMMEDIATE and got the following message:

> [Type 'InitiallyImmediateDeferrableStatic' is not assignable to type 'Deferrable'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOeSP.png)

I tried using the new keyword to fix the problem and it went away, but I don't understand why. I didn't find anything in the documentation that suggests the need to use it that way.